# Backwards Compatible Ros Commands To Find System Headers (Fuerte -> Electric)

Tags: catkin, ros-fuerte, ros-electric, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All,

I am trying to update some CMake files for a colleague since he is using Electric and I need to use Fuerte.  I would like to update the CMake files using ROS's CMake macros, environment variables and console commands...  Note these are not rosmake files but simple cmake files that use some of ROS's libraries.

However, some of the core headers (such as rosbag.h or ros.h) no longer follow a simple `rospack find [package]`.  This call returns me to `/opt/ros/fuerte/share` directory.

Is it possible to somehow use `rosbuild_find_ros_package` and prefix `/include` in such a way that it works for all packages in **Fuerte** and **Electric**

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45766/backwards-compatible-ros-commands-to-find-system-headers-(fuerte--%3E-electric)/) by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 296 on 2012-10-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not really understand the actual problem. What do you mean with 'rosmake files'? I never had problems to build electric nodes under fuerte and vice versa apart of some tf related issues.

If your problem is that you cannot use the builtin rosbuild macros (which should definitely work in both distros), I guess it might be because you are using `rospack find` to generate cflags and ldflags. Use `rospack export` instead. For instance, to get the cflags, you can call:

```
rospack export --lang=cpp --attrib=cflags
```

and to get the linker flags:

```
rospack export --lang=cpp --attrib=lflags
```

Rosbuild uses exactly these commands to infer the correct flags, i.e. it does not use `rospack find` for generating compiler and linker flags.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on 2012-10-15**:
Hi Lorenz, I am not build a node but a separate c++ program that happens to use ROS libraries... My colleague succeeded in this but he hardcoded a lot of paths.  I would like to redo his CMake's with non hardcoded paths so both Electric and Fuerte could be used.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-15**:
That's why I'm saying you should not use `rospack find` to get the path to a package and generate cflags and lflags from that path but you should use `rospack export`. In cmake, you can use `execute_process` and then add the output to your cmake flags. Btw. in fuerte you could also use pkgconfig.